# can python and php access same mysqldb?

Tags: php, python, mysql

Is it possible to access same mysql database using python and php.Beacause I am developing a video searching website which based on semantics. Purposely I have to use python and JavaEE. So I have to make a datbase to store video data. But it should be accessed through both python and javaEE, I can use php to interfacing between javaEE mysql database. But my problem is python can access the same database.?

I new to here and developing. I appreciate your kindness. Think I can get a best solution

Comment: yes, mysql allows concurrent connections

Comment: Why not try it and see if it works? (But, the answer is indeed "yes".)

Answer (score 1):

It's a database. It doesn't care what language or application you're using too access it. That's one of the benefits of having standards like the MySQL protocol, SQL in general, or even things like TCP/IP: They allow different systems to seamlessly inter-operate.

Answer (score 0):

Like @tadman said, yes.
All you care about is making a new connection and obtaining a cursor in each of your program (no matter what language).
The cursor is what does what you want (analogous to executing an actual query in whatever program you're using).